# Developing UI for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, mobile

I am planning to develop an Android based mobile for my Human Computer Interaction based project. I am looking for a UI designing application for Android platform. Can it be achieved with Eclipse or is there a better way of developing UI for Android applications that could be used directly with coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly code your UI too if you want to. It just takes long, and you open a window for errors.

Developing UI with eclipse using XML is great and easy, why don't you want to use it?

If by UI you mean "not-the-basic-UI", then it's possible too with eclipse - if you want a customized view then you code it, and if you want the normal UI views to look differently, theres a way to do that too (I'm pretty sure you can set your own pictures for `button-state-pressed`, `button-state-selected` and so on...)

You need to be more specific with what you want to do.

Comment: I want to use rich styled UI components, I don want to use normal button styles. I need to build my UI with these components, but in a drag and drop fashion.

Comment: Eclipse has a, sort of, drag and drop UI designer in ADT. But it's for the basic UI components only... I don't know of any other way.

Comment: Well thanks for the Info, If I can use custom images as button then I suppose It can solve my problem .

Comment: This is what you need: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 1):

Use java EE eclipse with (Android Development Tools) plug-in. Upgrade the android SDK in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has an extension called ADT (Android Development Tools).

Hope you have installed it. Here is the link for [installing](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) Android in Eclipse.

Eclipse provides the help for design the UI for android. It is just drag and drop.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I would check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a builtin GUI builder that is fairly good, there is also [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/), which may be slightly easier to use. I would recommend using Eclipse's builder myself, both are somewhat limited without hand-coding XML really.

Quick side note: Be sure NOT to use AbsoluteLayout, as I have seen a few people starting out with Android programming fall into the pitfall of thinking it will make GUI design easier. Issues will arise very quickly.

Comment: I thought I could depend on GUI builder that comes with Eclipse to  build my UI with Rich UI components, unlike normal button ( with default style). I would like have a UI with styled buttons and menus. Can we do this in Eclipse or DroidDraw ? Also I am new to android and I am not sure of the GUI building capabilities of Eclipse for Android. How hard is hand-coding a XML for custom layout  rather than using a GUI builder ?